# Laravel "belongsTo" function. Not exactly sure how this works. Help to access related model info from Blade template

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I am having issues understanding the "belongsTo" method in a class I am working with.
I have an "Asset" model which wasn't written by me, but I'd guess it works, and it has this function where I am trying to access the 'name' property of the "AssetMake" table (Which foreign and primary key args look about right):

```
public function assetMake()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(AssetMake::class, 'assetmake_id', 'id');
}
```

In a blade template that looks something like this, with the $asset variable injected in (and succesfuly already being used on the same page):

```
                        @foreach($assets as $asset)

                            <tr>
                                <td width="5%" class="filter_id"><a href="/fleet-fuel/assets/{{ $asset['unit_id'] }}__r">{{ $asset['unit_id'] }}</a></td>
                                <td width="20%" class="filter_type">{{ $asset['TypeName'] }}</td>
                                <td width="25%">{{ $asset['description'] }}</td>
                                <td width="20%">{{ $asset->assetMake()->get() }}</td>
                            </tr>

                        @endforeach
```

"AssetMake" looks like this, do I need a corresponding "hasMany" function?:

```
 class AssetMake extends Model
{
    use ModelDateSerializeNonISO;
    protected $table = 'assetmake';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $hidden = ['updated', 'created'];
}
```

I have tried acessing the injected $asset variable in a blade template as such:

```
<td width="20%">{{ $asset->assetMake->get }}</td>
<td width="20%">{{ $asset->assetMake->get() }}</td>
<td width="20%">{{ $asset->assetMake()->get }}</td>
<td width="20%">{{ $asset->assetMake->name }}</td>
<td width="20%">{{ $asset->assetMake()->name }}</td>
```

The 'name' property of the assetmake table is what I really need access to here.
Is this some kind of lazy/eager loading problem? I'm just not sure exactly what's happening here, and why I can't access the property. I've checked in various sources, and nothing I've tried works, but I'm sure it's fairly straight forward. Any tips?

Comment: First of all, this is right: `$asset->assetMake->name`. Do you get any error message?

Comment: This si the error when using "$asset->assetMake->name" - "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object"

Comment: Also, the other instances of the $asset object are succesfully being read and displaying on that page using the {{ $asset['description'] }} syntax.

Comment: I have also tried $asset['assetMake']['name'] and $asset['assetMake']->name and I have checked the values in the database are not null.

Comment: What does `{{ $asset->assetMake->toSql() }}` output?

Answer (score 1):

The way to access a related model is to call it as you would normally call a property. So something like `$asset->assetMake->name` should work.

Behind the scenes, I believe Laravel uses PHP's magic methods to create properties on the model based on the method names so that they point to the related model (parent or child).

Similarly, if you have a `hasMany` relationship like so:

```php
public function children()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Child::class, 'child_id',);
}
```

You can access the `children` just by calling `$parent->children`.

And if you need to access the Child query builder from the parent, you have to call the `children()` method.

E.g

```php
$parent->children()->create($childData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I worked it out. It was an issue with the controller. I'm still working this out and the magic in Laravel can be confusing to me. I added the line "->join('assetmake', 'assetmake.id', 'asset.assetmake_id')" to the controller query. And added to the select statement as well 'assetmake.name as AssetMakeName'

```
$assets = FleetFuel::where('fleet_fuel.customer_id', $user->customer_id)
                        ->where('fleet_fuel.isOrphan', 0)
                        ->where('fleet_fuel.hours', '>=', 0) // -1.00 = first ever record
                        ->where('fleet_fuel.burn', '>=', 0) // -1.00 = first ever record
                        ->join('asset', function($join) {
                            $join->on('fleet_fuel.unit_id', '=', 'asset.Unit_ID');
                            $join->on('fleet_fuel.customer_id', '=', 'asset.Customer_ID');
                        })                          
                        ->join('assettype', 'assettype.ID', 'asset.assettype_id')
                        ->join('assetmake', 'assetmake.id', 'asset.assetmake_id')
                        ->select('fleet_fuel.unit_id', DB::raw('max(fleet_fuel.delivery) as lastfuel'), 'asset.description', 'asset.Rego', 'assettype.Name as TypeName', 'assetmake.name as AssetMakeName')
                        ->groupBy('fleet_fuel.unit_id')->get();

        return view('fleetFuel.assets',
            [
                'companyName' => $companyName,
                'assets' => $assets
            ]
        );
```

And then accesed it in the blade view:

```
<td width="20%" class="filter_make">{{ (isset($asset['AssetMakeName'])) ? ($asset['AssetMakeName']) : ("No make available")}}</td>
```

Comment: That's one way to do it with query builder but this is not an eloquent relation. So it might work but it's not the best way to do this.